VBA Submitting Batch Emails to Outlook - Efficiency
Is there any way to submit a collection of MailItem to outlook and instruct it to send them all at once?
Right now my code will loop through thousands of email addresses and send an email every iteration. It takes hours to complete. Below is a redacted section of code.
    Do
        emailBody = "email body"
    
        Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With OutlookMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "test@test.com"
            .To = "test@test.com"
            .BCC = "test@test.com"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .HTMLBody = "<font style=""font-family: Poppins; font-size: 11pt;"">" & emailBody & "</font>"
            .Send
        End With
        
        ' Increment by the number of rows that were on this email.
        currRow = currRow + 1
        
    Loop While currRow < 2000

If it is possible to create a batch of emails and send them all at once, is it more efficient than waiting for outlook to send before moving on to the next email creation?

Do you need to send exactly the same mail (body, subject etc.) to all recipients? If so, you can create a list ("MyListAddress") of a lot of recipients and send the mail to it... If not, please better explain what you try doing.

The body will change depending on recipient. My code will determine information about each recipient then send them an email with that information. Right now I am sending an email each iteration of the loop. I am asking if there any other ways to do this since I would imagine calling MailItem.Send every iteration will be slower than a theoretical 'SendAll' method.

If the respective email(s) are not the same, I am afraid you do not have other choice.

If concerned about tying up Excel add DoEvents to the loop.

MailItem.Send is asynchronous: it does not wait for the submission to finish. If you comment our Send or replace it with Save, your code will take just as long.
